# DynamoDBMapper.save() stops working in app after a couple of hours

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm using DynamoDB to store device data.  The calls to DynamoDB are triggered an Intent configured with AlarmManager.  My code looks like:

MainActivity:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Pool_ID", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );
   AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
```

AsyncTask called within IntentService (triggered via AlarmManager):

```
private class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        sendSMS(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            sendSMS("saving..."); // send to myself
            Data data = new Data();
            Data.setData(params[0]);
            DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE);
            DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(MainActivity.client, dynamoDBMapperConfig);
            sendSMS("saving...");
            dynamoDBMapper.save(data);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
            return "failed...";
        }
        return "success...";
    }
}
```

When my app first loads and runs I see data saved to DynamoDB.  After a couple of hours data stops saving and I don't see an error in the log.  Any ideas why DynamoDBMapper.save stops working after a couple of hours?

**EDIT 1:** Added sendSMS() method I used for debugging.  When I initially start my app I get the sending, saving, success SMS messages.  After a few hours I only get the sending and saving SMS messages, and I never get the error message.

**EDIT 2:**  Added onPostExecute to AsyncTask

Comment: Do you see any error when it stops working? Can you add it to the post?

Comment: No error message.  I've updated to post to include debugging I've added.

Comment: Are you not seeing any exception message that you are logging in catch block?

Comment: No exception is thrown.  I've updated my code above, seems onPostExecute isn't being called.

Comment: Just to clarify, I've added onPostExecute to my AsyncTask.  When I initially start my app I get the "success...", however after some time I only get the 2 "saving..." messages.